# PayPal retrieving payment details through notify_url. Python & Flask

Tags: python, paypal, flask, paypal-ipn

I am using a PayPal button to accept payments for my site, but I need a way to retrieve transaction details. The obvious way would be to use notify URL.
I am using Flask.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/purchase", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def purchase():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form["item_name"]
        tx = request.form["txn_id"]
        email = request.form["payer_email"]
        return "Name: {0} \nTransaction ID: {1} \nEmail: {2}".format(name, tx, email)
    else:
        return """
<html>
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="www.site.com/purchase">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submit" class="buttonBox">
</form>
</html>
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run("0.0.0.0", port = 80)
```

Am I right in thinking that 'payer_email' and 'txn_id' are POST data from the payment form?

I do not have a domain name or webserver so I am unable to test the return values from notify_url

But most importantly, would this correctly retrieve the email of the buyer and transaction code?

Thanks :)

Note: this is a test case; I do use templates

Comment: "I do not have a domain name or webserver so I am unable to test". You don't need a custom domain or separate webserver to test flask applications. Just install it on your computer and run it locally using the built-in flask dev server.

Comment: You can't test notify_url without a domain name. You cannot test it on local host. I'll add to main post

Comment: Just use your IP address or create a subdomain that points to your local test server.  I like to use sandbox.domain.com for my test servers just like PayPal does.